# Transfer folder and file from one server to remote server using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scripting

I'm fairly new in bash scripting and need help with some regex/logic to help me resolve the following testcase.

I have to transfer file with it's prefix from base location to remote server using bash script.

Scenario-

Server 1:
base location -  /dummy

prefix = a*

so here we have to go all folders inside the base location and transfer file with folder strcture on server2.

Server 2:
base location - /demo

so we need all files with their respective folders in server 2.

```
Example -  
Server 1:  
          /dummy/d1/d2/a01.txt
          /dummy/a1/b01.txt
          /dummy/d1/d2/d3/a02.txt
```

Output on remote server -

```
Server 2: 
          /demo/d1/d2/a01.txt
          /demo/d1/d2/d3/a02.txt
```

After transferring files we have only have to delete files from the server1.

Any leads would be appriciated, Thank you!

We are expecting that files will be transfer to from server1 to server2 and we have to delete files after transferring from the  server1

Answer (score 0):

Run this `rsync` command on `Server2`:

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files --include='*/' --include='a*.txt' --exclude='*' username@Server1:/dummy/ /demo/
```